Installing a sillcock, can I slightly bend copper for an offset connection? Will making the inlet 3/4" from existing reduced 1/2" increase flow rate?
The hose bib at my parents' place hasn't been working for quite some time so I wanted to try my hand at replacing it with a frost-free sillcock. While water only dribbles out when the faucet is opened, the shut-off valve looks very corroded and I believe there's a blockage inside that is causing no flow; maybe the stem broke off inside.
The existing line for the outdoor spigot starts as 3/4" and is reduced to 1/2" right before the shut-off. So there's about 2' of 1/2" piping between the reducer and the hose bib outside.


The problem is that the hole in the wall is offset about 1.75" horizontally and 0.5" vertically to the rest of the line, and it looks like when it was originally installed, the plumber had bent the pipe to make the connection. Is it feasible for me to make a bend in some hard copper (type L) I already have? I watched a few videos on annealing hard copper and thought a minor offset like this one would be okay to do. I know I could probably do it with a couple of 45-deg elbows but I would imagine the fewer couplings I need to solder, the better.

Lastly, would I see any significant difference in flow rate just cutting out the entire 1/2" section and making the final connection to the sillcock a continuous 3/4"? I've been researching whether or not it would actually make a difference, given that the connected water meter is 5/8" (wouldn't this be the flow rate limiting factor for the rest of the house?), the 1/2" section is only about 2' long (I believe
the reducer definitely does decrease flow rate but I'm not sure to what extent due to the short distance), and the sillcock opening's bore size is already supposed to be small anyway (correct me if I'm wrong, but apparently the valve bore for a standard hose bib with 1/2" inlet is generally the same size as one with a 3/4" inlet - about 5/16" or so, so wouldn't flow rate also be limited due to this factor?), but haven't found a definite answer.

Copper pipe can be bent, but also quite easy to kink it(bad).  There are pipe/tube benders that should be used.  Can probably rent one(they might just let you use one at the store).  Adding some pex there will save problems with bending copper.

Flow rate should not change much.  Might find a higher pressure at the end of the 1/2 inch than at the 3/4 inch pipe.  There are calculations to be found, but I think the final gallons per minute should be close to equal for the two pipe sizes.

Changing from 1/2" to 3/4" won't help much (if at all) due to the restriction in the hose valve. If you really want to make a difference in flow, look for a high quality spigot with a full-port ball valve.

Whatever you do, I'd think about replacing that valve with the red handle while you're at it.

The shutoff valve appears to be a gate valve. These are notorious for sticking in the closed or partly closed position. Be sure to replace it with a modern ball valve. Could you unsweat the connections and reuse the curved section? Of course there is a fire risk!  Could this section be soft copper rather than hard copper? Before doing anything might be a good idea to use a lead detection reagent on the joints to make sure it is not lead solder. If it would be then you would not want to unsweat it, I think. Safest would be to cut and then remake with crimp connectors.

You haven't explained why flow rate is important. So I will ignore that since the original issue is that the outside hose bib only allows a trickle of water. You haven't said that the water pressure in the home is an issue, so I'll assume that is all ok.
The inside shutoff shows some corrosion. I would begin by replacing that. (It could be an issue if you shut off the water and then open the valve again)
Since you have a line in place that is 1/2", use it. Why make simple stuff complicated.
Replace the bib outside when you replace the shutoff inside.  Now you have 2 new valves that will work properly. (If you prefer, you can instal the frostless silcock. But again, is it really needed with the inside shut off? )
This will correct the issue. If there is some reason that the flow rate of GPM out of the hose bib is important for timed irrigation, device fill or some other reason, your have not told us that.   Otherwise the 1/2" hose bib will provide enough water for normal expected use.

Water pressure and flow rate are both good, but since I'm going to have to cut the pipe upstream of the shut off anyway, I thought I could easily cut into the 3/4" section instead to make the entire run 3/4" to improve the flow rate - even though it's not strictly necessary, I imagine it would be more convenient, even if it's just a little bit, when I'm filling up containers of water (there is a section of sub-irrigated systems in yard for summer gardening).
Of course, this only matters if the flow rate actually increases - will it not? Will the hose valve limit the flow in either case?

The performance of the irrigation in relation to the size of the piping, will depend on the number and type of irrigation heads.  So that can't be answered without more information .  Generally, 1/2" pipe is enough to supply water to normal irrigation for an area of about 500 sq. feet.  The flow rate difference between the 1/2 and 3/4 pipes will be minimal.  In the scheme of what you are doing, not worth worrying about.   Of course the hose bib will be a limiting factor.  At pressure of X only so much water can pass through regardless of the size pipe feeding it.

There is no below-ground piping - just manual transfer of water for garden irrigation/storage tanks. So it sounds like I should just stick to 1/2" then to keep things simpler. Is it possible to use one of these to connect the shutoff to the sillcock inlet? Or even directly thread the inlet into the shutoff to make it even simpler?
